# Burst control over multiple ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of `$.get` requests that I handle using

```
$.when(...requests).then((...responses)=>{})
```

The problem is theres a burst rate on the API Im calling, so sending all the requests at once will make a fraction of them to fail.

Is there a simple way of making these requests not to send immediatly using jquery?

Comment: if there is a possibility you can try grouping the request. If not then you just have to set a timer and send the next request

Comment: Could try chunking the initial arrays that are used to create individual requests and doing  `$.when( $when1).then($when2).then...`. Hard to help without more detail about how `requests` gets generated

Comment: Also what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Using jquery 2.2.4

Comment: What is the burst rate?

Comment: 50 requests per second

Comment: The requests are simple $.ajax objects whose urls come from a list.

Answer (score 0):

$.get should return also Promise interface so you can chain them like this example:

```js
var urls = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
var responses = [];

/*---- vanilla js example for use in snippet ------- */
function fakeGet(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, url + ' response'));
}

urls.reduce((chain, url) => {
  return chain.then(res => {
    res? responses.push(res) : '';
    console.log('getting: ' + url);
    return fakeGet(url);
  });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(res => {
  responses.push(res);
  console.log('Complete!\n' + responses.join("\n"));
});

/* --------------- end of vanilla snippet ---------------*/


/* ------- using jQuery $.get --------------------
urls.reduce((chain, url) => {
  return chain.then(res => {
    res? responses.push(res) : '';
    return $.get(url);
  });
}, $.when()).then(res => {
  responses.push(res);
  console.log('Complete!\n' + responses.join("\n"));
});
---------------------------------------- */
```