# Query an API multiple times based on a list of tokens

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, reactjs, for-loop

My `getSingleContract(data)` function retrieves id(s) and fill in the `filelist` array. When this procces succeeds, I need the `retrieveUploadForContract(data)` function to run as many times as there are items in the former array because the API can process only one ID at a time.

Currently, I am able to invoke the API only once as I am invoking with the first ID alone.
Once again, if 5 ids have been retrieved the API has to be invoked 5 times.
To handle multiple ids I tried using `map` but unsuccessfully.

**How can I achieve this ?**

### Webservice response

[image: webservice-response]

### My code

```
export function _getSingleContract(data) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    let url = "/contracts/read?access_token=" + token;
    let BASE = "http://172.104.167.150:9082"
    let actualurl = BASE + url;
    Api._callAPI(actualurl, 'GET', data, (type, dt) => {
        if (type == 'success') {
            dispatcher.dispatch({
                type: 'SingleContract',
                data: dt,
            });

            let data = {
                file: dt.contract.fileList[0],
            }

            // dt.contract.fileList.map((el) => el)
            this._retrieveUploadForContract(data);
        }
    });
}

export function _retrieveUploadForContract(data) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    let contractId = localStorage.getItem('contractIdforview');
    let url = "/contracts/retrieve?id=" + contractId + "&access_token=" + token;
    let BASE = "http://172.104.167.150:9082"
    let actualurl = BASE + url;
    UploadRetrieveApi._callAPI(actualurl, 'GET', data, (type, dt) => {
        if (type == 'success') {
            dispatcher.dispatch({
                type: 'RetrieveUploadFile',
                data: dt,
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So is this angularjs or reactjs?

Comment: reactjs! but the loop functionality only required you can make use of anything

Comment: please anyone guide me  in solving this

Comment: Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432121/burst-control-over-multiple-ajax-requests/48433058#48433058). Maybe you can find it useful..